# rust - return type from generic function with traits

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand how generic functions works in Rust. Here's my code:

```
fn evaluate<T: std::ops::Mul>(portfolio: T, quote: T) -> T {
    portfolio * quote
}
```

And I getting the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
9  | fn evaluate<T: std::ops::Mul>(portfolio: T, quote: T) -> T {
   |                                                          - expected `T` because of return type
10 |     portfolio * quote
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found associated type
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
             found associated type `<T as std::ops::Mul>::Output`
   = note: you might be missing a type parameter or trait bound
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html for docs on the `Add` trait. The simple solution is to change your bound to be `T: std::ops::Mul<Output = T>`, but the explanation is longer.

Comment: Understand... a kind of. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust does not assume that multiplication of to values of type `T` always results in a new value of type `T`. Instead, the `Mul` trait has an *associated type* `Output` that specifies the return type of the multiplication. The error message mentions that type as "found associated type `<T as std::ops::Mul>::Output`". So the easiest solution is to change the return type of your function to the assoicated type:

```
fn evaluate<T: std::ops::Mul>(portfolio: T, quote: T) -> <T as std::ops::Mul>::Output {
    portfolio * quote
}
```

A common example where `Output` does not match the input type is multiplying two references – the output will usually be an owned type, not a reference again.